# How do I make the keyboard come down when you tap return Swift

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, swift2

**Please do not mark as duplicate as I have looked at other posts and they do not work as I am using Swift 2 <--- I think this is the reason.**

Hi, I have a UITextField, and when I tap on it a keyboard appears, as usual. But, when I tap on the return key nothing happens. I have tried using:

```
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;

    }
```

But that does not work, as when I tap return nothing happens. Is there any other working ways that I could use, or is it a mistake in my code. Here is the whole of the class:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {



@IBOutlet var FullName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var StartDate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var EndDate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var Room: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var Occupancy: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var Email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var Number: UITextField!

func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property

    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["email@YourApp.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("App Feedback")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("This is an automated email. \n  Hello, My name is \(FullName.text). \n I would like to book a room from  \(StartDate.text) to  \(EndDate.text). \n I would like the  \(Room.text) for \(Occupancy.text). \n You can Contact me at: \n  \(Email.text) and my phone number is: \(Number.text) \n Thank You", isHTML: false)

    return mailComposerVC
}

@IBAction func Send(sender: AnyObject) {
    let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



}
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;

    }



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you set the text field delegate ?

Comment: what is the text field delegate - Im new to swift

Comment: you have set the mail compose delegate, do you understand what's happening there and why you did it ? you don't appear to have implemented the only method in that protocol in your question code.

Comment: I don't understand the mail compose delegate, Isn't that unrelated

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.
Then you have to set your ViewConrtoller as the delegate for your textFields.
Remember to implement the `textFieldShouldReturn` function that is the one called when the return button is pressed. You can implement it like this to dismiss the keyboard:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your viewdidload function write :

> YOURTEXTFIELD.delegate = self

And

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
  textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Comment: When I put in the YOURTEXTFIELD.delegate = self it gives me an error: "Cannot assign value of type secondviewcontroller to type UItextfield delegate'